# How to check for field groups in Wordpress Advanced Custom Fields plugin?

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I'm using the acf Advanced Custom Fields plugin for Wordpress. 
I'm working with a generic template that outputs all field groups by default. 
As some fields are only shown on specific pages I'd like to determine what fields need to be outputted.
My current workaround is the following:

1, I created a acf- field group (e.g. with the name "My Field Group") in
    the backend;
 2, I set a role in the acf-menu for "My Field Group" to
    show it only on e.g. a specific page (the role could also be a category etc.)
 3, I created a custom field with a checkbox and the
    name "mygroup" within "My Field Group" that always returns "yes".

4, Then in the code I can check if the group "My Field Group" is available on a
    page by checking the value of the custom field "mygroup". If yes, it will return all fields of "My Field Group"

The code:

```
//check if the field group "My Field Group" is available by checking the value of its custom field "mygroup" 
<?php if(get_field('mygroup') == "yes") { ?>
    <div>
        //load all other fields in the field group "My Field Group"
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

As this requires an additional field only to check if the field group is available on a page (respectively to determine the role), I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to achieve that

[image: acf editor]

[image: page]

**Update:**
Here's the feedback from the programmer:

> ACF does not save any information about the specific field group that
>   appeared on the post, only the field values.
>
> I believe that your method is minimal, efficient and smart. I would
>   continue to use this.
>
> Cheers Elliot

Comment: What are you referring as Field Group? What do you mean by "available"? Where is this single checkbox put?

Comment: See, your Question started with only a fraction of the global context. Now, after 2 missed answers, the general picture is more clear. For the Q to be understood, one will have to navigate through comments. My suggestion is that you edit the Q one more time to make it *really answerable*. And use your own field names, [Tim Maia](https://www.google.com/search?q=tim+maia) was intended as a brazilian easter-egg but now is making things more confusing :P

Comment: IMO, it'll be crystal clear if you add a snapshot to items 2 and 3.

Comment: ok, i  did that. can you restore your first answer? i think it's good to know who one can target a specific field group and it might be helpful to asnwer my question

Comment: I merged the first and second versions of the Q, does it addresses all your doubts?

Answer (score 0):

**For simply checking if the field `mygroup` is enabled, use:**

```
// call the function only once
$group = get_field('mygroup');

if( $group ) { 
    ?>
    <div>
        <?php do_your_magic_with_the_other_fields(); ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

---

**For checking for the whole `My Field Group`:**

An ACF Field Group is a custom post type stored in `wp_posts` table. The fields inside this Field Group are stored in `wp_postmeta` table.

So, you'll have to check for the post existence.

[image: acf field group]

Same "field group" in the database:

[image: acf field group in the database]
*<sup>click to enlarge ⤴</sup>*

---

#### Solution: use [get_page_by_title()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title)

In my example:

```
if( get_page_by_title( 'TimMaia', OBJECT, 'acf' ) )
{
    // Your stuff
}
```

Comment: thank you.it's not a coding problem. the code works fine. I'm just wondering how to target a field group of the acf-plugin dirctly (without  creating an extra custom field that sets a variable for each group)

Comment: Thank you for letting me know how to target the group! There's just one problem: The if-statement will always return the content of the field group "TimMaia" as it's always true (even if a certain page doesn't use this group on it's page)

Comment: sorry for the confusion ;)